# Xamarin.Forms - How do I make a click counter?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms for Android app development and would like to create a counter whenever the player taps the screen. How do I make a counter to count the number of taps on the screen? I am using Visual Studio 2019 if that helps. Thank you!

Here's my xaml.cs code (don't mind the InitializeComponent and the number of curly braces. Those are fine):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgreW.png)

Here's my .xaml code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYCbf.png)

Comment: Do you understand how to respond to a tap event?  Do you understand how to create a counter variable and increment it?

Comment: I don't understand either. I am very new to this.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do this

In XAML

```
<StackLayout Spacing="15">
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="0" x:Name="lblCount" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <Button Text="Increment" Clicked="Increment"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In XAML.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int lblValue = 0;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Increment(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblValue++;
        lblCount.Text = lblValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

That's a simple way to solve this, if you need uses Binding or other feature tell me.

Just like Jason said I suggest you look at the documentation

Comment: The code isn't recognizing lblCount in the .cs file. Guessing from what you said and what I've looked online, it's a binding issue. How do I go about solving this? I've looked at the documentation but I couldn't quite grasp the concept for this particular problem.

Comment: Hi, lblCount is the value of property NAME in <Label>(x:name on previous answer). That's name identifies the component which displays the text.
 
The documentation for you that is apparently starting with Xamarin may be not so understandable, so I suggest you search for sample applications, and if you don't find samples you need, you can search them in C # instead of using Xamarin.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not sure how to solve the issue. I'm using different possible solutions and it's always saying that lblCount "does not exist in the current context" in the .cs file.

Comment: Put here an screenshot of xaml code and xaml.cs code(the label's code), or just paste the code here, may be i can help you.

Comment: Ok, I updated my post with screenshots of the code fles.

Comment: Please Click right button in your solution and Clean Solution, after this try run again. Andif still not working, take a look the example [here](https://github.com/lemarcelo/CountTest.git) and try to find where is the error in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can add gesture recognizer to your main frame(stacklayout in example)

XAML

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="#313FA0">
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped"/>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

 //All page stuff


</StackLayout>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   int taps = 0;
    private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        taps++;
        Console.Writeline(taps.ToString());
    }
}
```